# Discord chatbot integrated with OpenAI times out after 3 queries – Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 20 seconds

Tags: python, async-await, discord, openai-api

I am creating a Discord chatbot using the OpenAI's Assistant API.

Below is my code, should be fairly simple

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
from openai import OpenAI
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from assistant_api import upload_file, create_assistant

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Discord client setup
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# OpenAI API setup
openai_api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
client = OpenAI(api_key=openai_api_key)

# Content setup
files = []
for file in os.listdir("MY_FOLDER"):
    if file.endswith(".md"):
        files.append(upload_file(os.path.join("MY_FOLDER", file), client))
instructions = """
ADD BOT INSTRUCTIONS HERE
"""
assistant = create_assistant(files, client, instructions)
assistant_id = assistant.id

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate response
# --------------------------------------------------------------
async def generate_response(conversation_log, client, assistant_id):
    # Retrieve the Assistant
    assistant = client.beta.assistants.retrieve(assistant_id)

    # Clear the thread and re-add the last 15 messages
    thread = client.beta.threads.create()

    for message in conversation_log:
        client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            role=message['role'],
            content=message["content"],
        )

    # Run the assistant
    run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        assistant_id=assistant.id,
    )

    # Wait for completion
    while run.status != "completed":
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(thread_id=thread.id, run_id=run.id)

    # Retrieve the Messages
    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread.id)
    new_message = messages.data[0].content[0].text.value
    print(f"Generated message: {new_message}")
    return new_message

# Event when the bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is online!')

# Event when a message is received
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages from bots
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    # Respond only in specific channel
    if message.channel.id != int(os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')):
        return

    # Ignore messages starting with '!'
    if message.content.startswith('!'):
        return

    try:
        await message.channel.typing()
        prev_messages = [message async for message in message.channel.history(limit=15)]
        
        prev_messages.reverse()

        conversation_log = []
        for msg in prev_messages:
            if msg.content.startswith('!'):
                continue
            if msg.author.id != bot.user.id and msg.author.bot:
                continue
            role = 'assistant' if msg.author.id == bot.user.id else 'user'
            conversation_log.append({
                "role": "user",  # this should be "role" as defined above but for some reason it is not accepted by the API; 
                # it only accepts "user" but not "system" for some reason; this is not ideal but this is the best workaround at the moment
                "content": msg.content,
                "name": ''.join(e for e in msg.author.name if e.isalnum() or e == '_')
            })

        # Generate the response using the assistant_api module
        new_message = await generate_response(conversation_log, client, assistant_id)

        await message.reply(new_message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'ERR: {e}')
        raise

# Run the bot
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

It all works fine for the first 3 messages, but after 3 messages the OpenAI API struggles to give a reply and after a while I get this error. Does anyone have any idea how this issue might be fixed and what might be causing it?

```
2024-02-15 18:27:10 WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 20 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/bot_simpler_structure.py", line 120, in <module>
    bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 671, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 638, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1971, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/events.py", line 84, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/bot_simpler_structure.py", line 112, in on_message
    new_message = await generate_response(conversation_log, client, assistant_id)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/bot_simpler_structure.py", line 48, in generate_response
    client.beta.threads.messages.create(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/threads/messages/messages.py", line 92, in create
    return self._post(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1200, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 889, in request
    return self._request(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 918, in _request
    response = self._client.send(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 915, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 943, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 980, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1016, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 231, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 196, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 101, in handle_request
    return self._connection.handle_request(request)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 110, in handle_request
    ) = self._receive_response_headers(**kwargs)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 175, in _receive_response_headers
    event = self._receive_event(timeout=timeout)
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 211, in _receive_event
    data = self._network_stream.read(
  File "/root/workspace/discord_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 126, in read
    return self._sock.recv(max_bytes)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1234, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1107, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
```

Comment: Update: Seems like this issue happens at random times, and sometimes it doesn't happen. Maybe it's the OpenAI Assistant API (still in beta) which is a bit temperamental.